# Mulitlayer Perceptron prediction result not only as a double, also as String (using Weka (Java))

Tags: machine-learning, weka, prediction, perceptron, multi-layer

I would like to make a prediction using multilayer perceptron. For this purpose, I have created test data to be predicted.
Now I go through all records in a for loop and want to append the prediction:

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < datapredict1.numInstances(); i1++) {      
            double clsLabel1 = mlp.classifyInstance(datapredict1.instance(i1));
            datapredict1.instance(i1).setClassValue(clsLabel1); 
            String s = datapredict1.instance(i1) + "," + clsLabel1;
            writer11.write(s.toString());
            writer11.newLine();
            System.out.println(datapredict1.instance(i1) + "," + clsLabel1);
        }
```

The result output is as follows:
0.178571,0.2,0.181818,0.333333,0,09:15,**0.849899**,0.8498991728827364
0.414835,0,0.454545,0.666667,0,16:15,**0.850662**,0.85066198399766

How is it possible that here, not only the probability is displayed, but also the string value
As for example:
0.178571,0.2,0.181818,0.333333,0,09:15,**"Value2"**,0.8498991728827364
0.414835,0,0.454545,0.666667,0,16:15,**"Value4"**,0.85066198399766

Answer (score 0):

The [classifyInstance](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html#classifyInstance-weka.core.Instance-) method of a classifier returns the regression value for numeric class attributes or the index of the most likely class label for nominal ones.

In the latter case, cast the returned `double` to an `int` and use the [value(int)](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html#value-int-) method of the class attribute of your dataset to obtain the label string.